# ORA-0911 Invalid Character in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
String query2 = "INSERT INTO \"jadwal_guru_m\" (`kd_transaksi`, `kelas`, `mapel`, `pengajar`, `tanggal`, `hari`, `ruangan`, `waktu`)"+ " VALUES ('"+kode+"','"+kelas+"','"+mapel+"','"+pengajar+"','"+tanggal+"','"+hari+"','"+ruangan+"','"+waktu+"')";
st2.executeUpdate(query2);
```

that was my query in netbeans. And, things inside the values brackets was variables.

When I run into it it shows `"ORA-0911 Invalid Character"` as an error message, any suggeston to fix this?

Comment: Use prepared statements. it is muxh easter to read.

Comment: And much safer too...

Comment: `\`` is an invalid character for an identifier in SQL. Either use double quotes (if needed - that will make your names case **sensitive**) or don't use quoted identifiers at all (highly recommended). More details about identifiers are in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't use forward quotes to denote columns - just lose them and you should be OK:

```
String query2 = "INSERT INTO \"jadwal_guru_m\" (kd_transaksi, kelas, mapel, pengajar, tanggal, hari, ruangan, waktu) VALUES ('"+kode+"','"+kelas+"','"+mapel+"','"+pengajar+"','"+tanggal+"','"+hari+"','"+ruangan+"','"+waktu+"')";
st2.executeUpdate(query2);
```

Additionally, you should probably use a `PreparedStatement` instead of concatinating strings, just so it can save you the hassle of type conversions, worrying about SQL injectoins, etc.

Comment: I wonder if the table name is really in lowercase. That might be the next problem ahead.

Comment: @Codo indeed - although if it isn't the error would be quite straight forward (ORA-942, and not ORA-911).

Comment: @Mureinik - yeah it does help. and now i have a group by error using another sql. is there a way to use group by or having in Oracle, since im new to this